# Glob for matching everything but . and

Tags: shell, wildcards

I came up with the following glob for matching everything but `.` and `..`:

`* .[!.]* ..?*`

Does this really do its job?

Comment: for `ls` you can use `ls -A`..

Comment: It does, in Bourne-like shells. See also the link I gave above.